# What is the appropriate site for asking questions related to electronic parts and manufacturers?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I've a DIP I scavenged from a old receiver but I cannot find a datasheet that's why I've to ask a question about its manufacturer but I don't know on which site I should ask the question. I've tried to look for a appropriate site https://stackexchange.com/sites# but cannot find any.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Electrical Engineering site is the one you are looking for.  It's for:

> Electrical Engineering:  For electronics and electrical engineering
> professionals, students, and enthusiasts.

The link to the site is here:  https://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Just a shout-out to thank you for your contributions here on Meta.SE, despite minimal activity on the other sites in the network (or do you have a separate account for that? – anyway, none of my business :)) That rarely bodes well, but I'm happy to see an exception to the rule. Keep up the good work!

Comment: @Glorfindel Thank you!  I'm not really active on any other site, except to respond to SmokeDetector's spam reports; I prefer to stay where I can report and request to improve  SE's sites, and that place is usually Meta.